# Ajax auto update not updating

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Hello I'm working on a shoutbox and I need help with auto updating them via ajax.

Here is my shoutbox with ?getShouts=true at the end:

[image: img]

Here is my shoutbox without that:

[image: img]

My goal here is to run a web request and get the contents of the shoutbox in ?getShouts and update on the page I'm in.

This PHP code is run on the top of the page:

```
if(!empty($_GET['getShouts']))
{
    $sbinfo = "";
    $rows = $db->query("SELECT * FROM shouts order by shoutid DESC limit 20");
    while($row = $rows->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC))
        $sbinfo .= $row['username'] . ": " . $row['shout'] . "<br />";
}
```

That stores the markup for the text into one string.

later in php file it displays the markup by: `if(!empty($_GET['getShouts'])) echo $markup;`

Here is my ajax I'm currently running:

```
<script>


        $(document).ready(function() {
            getMessages();
        });

        function getMessages()
        {

            //make request
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.open("GET", location.href+"?getShouts=true", true);
            req.send(null);
            document.getElementById("shouts-box").innerHTML = req.responseXML.getElementsById("shouts-box")[0].innerHTML;

            //loop
            window.setInterval(getMessages,3000);
        }
</script>
```

any ideas?

Comment: You might want to replace `setInterval` with `setTimeout` since every time you access `getMessages` you initialize a new `setInterval`, while the others keep running. Leave it for a day and your machine will stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for this using:

```
$('#div').load('index.php?getShouts=true #div');
```